# Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Tags: list, permissions, custom-list

I created a Custom List and Stop Inheritance and give the unique permissions to the list as contribute,when i am trying to insert an Item i am getting error  **"Access denied"**. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

Can any one help on this...

Comment: do you have permission on the site collection?

Comment: yes we are having permissions with limited access

Comment: This is high priority Issue,Please help

Comment: what template being used for the site collection? do you have fiddler and try to trace on which page/ item it throws the access denied? also ULS logs will give you more clue

Comment: seattle  master page,checked in logs but unable to identify the issue

Comment: without detail about the error, it is very hard....one did you try with inherited permission if it works?

Comment: I tried with Inherited Permissions,it is working fine but stopping inheritance not working

Comment: is it a publishing site? check if the user is part of style resource readers group....also restricted readers

Comment: Team site only,issue is with only particular list,reaming all lists are working fine.

Comment: Try to do the same action in other list/library, are you site collection administrator?

Comment: Does your list host a lookup field? Do you have access to the lookup target list?

Comment: Try the check permissions function in the list permissions page. See if the user has appropriate permissions. If he does, try giving read permissions to the user on the site/subsite in which list is hosted by adding the user to the visitors group.